# django-tastypie: Loading fields based on request

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a resources structure in tastypie similar to the following:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()

class ActivityResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Activity.objects.all()

class UserActivityResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'user')
    activity = fields.ToOneField(ActivityResource, 'activity', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = UserActivity.objects.all()
        filtering = {
            'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'activity': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }
```

It is clearly a many to many objects relation.

Sometimes I want to retrieve the data from UserActivity using an specific id for this object, which gives me in the result the specific fields from UserActivity + User data related + Activity data related, which is pretty good, for example:

```
GET /api/v1/user_activity/{user_activity_id}/
```

Other times I want to retrieve the data from UserActivity based on, for example the id of the related User object, for example:

```
GET /api/v1/user_activity/?user={user_id}
```

This request works pretty good also.

Now, let's say that the {user_id} sent in the request has 10 related activities (ActivityResource) in the join object. So, when I look into the request execution, I can notice that the system is running the following queries to build the result:

```
select count(*) from user_activity where {filters} (building meta...ok)
```

And for each activity related (10 times):

```
select user_activity.* from user_activity where {filters} (getting user_activity data...ok)
select activity.* from activity where {filters} (getting activity data...ok)
select user.* from user where id={user_id} (getting user data...ok?)
```

The thing is, I already know the user used to find the related activities, then, I don't need to query again its data, and of course I am not interested in execute the same query **10 times**!

So, the question is...

Is there any way to optimize the process, so I can activate/deactivate the use of the related field *user* depending on the request to avoid useless queries? or in other words, to modify the related objects of the resource on the fly ?

Thank you.

BTW: I'm using django1.4, django-tastypie 0.9.11

Comment: please post the answer @tufla if you had